# angular 4 http.post not sending or working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am quite new to the latest version of Angular. `http.post` does not seem to work in anywhere in my application. I have tried things like:

```
this.http
    .post(this.bikesUrl, data, { headers: this.headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

...or...

```
this.http.post(this.config.apiEndpoint+'/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // set token property
                this.token = token;

                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));

                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        }).subscribe(result => {
      if (result === true) {
        // login successful
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else {
        // login failed
        this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        this.loading = false;
      }
    })
```

...or...

```
 var json = {var1: 'test'};
var params = 'json='+json;
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http.post("http://example.com/infoarray.php", params, headers ).subscribe (re => {
  console.log(re)
})
```

When I run this in the browser it is almost like the script is not there. I see no requests in the inspector. I am using Angular CLI

Comment: Are you able to narrow down which part it doesn't work? Like is the whole app working fine except the `http.post`?

Comment: Yes, the all application works. but the http.post

Comment: Can you show me your API Code?

Comment: http.get is working?

Comment: http.get does not work either. I am using Chrome. Shouldn't I be seeing these requests on the inspection console, such as getting a 404 error. My API is built on Lumen with Dingo. The first part is to login so I need to no for sure whether the requests are being sent to debug.

Comment: People usually forget to `subscribe` to an observable which you did not forget to. So, there must be another problem lying underneath. Do you not see anything on network tab?

Comment: are there any errors in console?

Comment: Yes there are some No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors but not related to the script. Just fonts and css files in the index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. I have been following a tutorial that included a fake backend script for testing which has been affecting all requests.

Just in case someone is having the same problem or has been following this tutorial; http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial make sure to disable the fake backend.

I simply removed these providers;

```
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/fake-backend';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing in my Ionic 3 App.

```
//in my ApiProvider

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

http.post("http://localhost/login", params, options)
  .map(this.onLoginSuccess)
  .catch(this.onError);

onLoginSuccess(res: Response): Observable<LoginUserResponse> {
 return res.json();
}

private onError(error: Response | any) {
  console.error(error.message || error);
  return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is your http properly instantiated? try below method please, it works for sure:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    // Post
    MyPost() {
        this.http.post(.....);
      }
  }
```

If still not working, your data might be error, like this.config, username, password ... all valid?

Answer (score 0):

Other mistake we generally do is we forget to import Headers from @angular/http. It will not give any error but requests will not work. Please try importing Headers as
`import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';`

Comment: In angular 4 there no **Header** i think you mean **Headers**

Comment: Sorry for typo. It is headers. Thanks @AnupB